# Looking for Iseries / AS400 cl code to run lansa imports and exports

Tags: ibm-midrange, lansa

I am trying to set up a batch LANSA import and export command-line language program.

The prompting from LANSA is ambiguous as far as what goes where in a batch environment. I can prompt on the LANSA command with Import Option, but it's a little grey on what goes where.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem programming related.  I don't think SE has an appropriate site.  You might try midrange.com mailing lists http://www.midrange.com/#lists

Comment: There seems to be two points to this post. One is a question on how to write a Lansa Import and Export CL program. That is indeed programming related. The other seems to be an attempt to start up a Forum. That is not programming related, and SO is not a Forum style site. There are quite a few people here who will cull any new post that is not a Question or direct answer to that question, and anything that looks like Discussion. If that is all you want, just post questions, or write answers. To fix this question so it doesn't get deleted, you should edit out the community building portion.

Comment: will edit out social comment